# What is the most appropriate way to differentiate different editions of Anima?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

The original version of Anima has no English translation, except possibly on the servers of Fantasy Flight Games.  The Spainish revised edition is available in English, and is the text I assume is indicated by the [anima-beyond-fantasy] tag it is different from the original version in meaningful but small scale ways.  The Core Exxet, which is the most recent major revision to the Core rules, is also only available in Spanish, and also changes the system in meaningful but small scale ways.

When I ask questions about Anima, I want to be able to get answers for the version of the game that uses the English Core Rulebook, which I own, and not the Spanish Core Exxet, which I don't, because practical answers for the later system often don't apply to the earlier one and vice versa.  It seems to me the best way to do this is a tag, but I am unsure what a tag should be called so as to be easily found by other askers.

What is the best way of differentiating the editions in questions and, if that method is a tag, what should the tag be called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Put it in your question

Tags are for finding questions, not for straitjacketing you to sticking to the tag.  If you only want information from one edition, and we do not have edition tags for it, just clarify in your question.  if you get answers from other editions, downvote them ruthlessly.

Answer (score 5):

Anima isn't a large enough game to need edition tags. Simply make your requirements clear in your question. If we get questions about multiple editions of anima, we'll let the edition tags fall out naturally.